# How can I fix this Angular $scope issue?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a partial that uses one controller called CaseNotesCtrl. I am having problems accessing $scope variables inside of this partial. The code is this:

```
<div class="row" ng-show="$parent.loggedin" ng-controller="CaseNotesCtrl">
    <div class="col-sm-12 note
-field" ng-show="$parent.addingNote">
        <label for="noteEntry">Enter your note</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="noteEntry" rows="4" ng-model="newNote.note"></textarea>
        <br />
        <a href="" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger calicon-view note-save-button" ng-click="saveCaseNotes(note.Case.CaseID, note.User.UserID, note.NoteID)" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Save Note"  tooltip><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save"></span></a>
        <a href="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Cancel Adding Note" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger calicon-view note-cancel-button" ng-click="$parent.cancelNote();" tooltip>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <a href="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Add a Note" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger calicon-view note-add-button" ng-click="$parent.addNote();" ng-show="!$parent.addingNote" tooltip>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 note-list-heading" ng-repeat-start="note in caseNotes">
        <span class="note-header">Note entered by {{ note.User.DisplayName }} and was last edited on {{ note.ModifiedDate | date: "MM/dd/yyyy 'at' h:mma" }}</span><a href="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Edit This Note" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger calicon-view pull-right note-edit-button" ng-click="editNote(note.Case.CaseID, note.NoteID, note.Notes)" tooltip><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 note-text">
        {{ note.Notes }}
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat-end></div>
</div>
```

here is the controller code:

```
JBenchApp.controller('CaseNotesCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', 'HoldState', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams, HoldState) {

    // Management of case notes
    $scope.NotesCaseID = $routeParams.number;
    $scope.NotesUserName = localStorage.getItem('UserName');
    $scope.NotesUserRole = localStorage.getItem('UserRole');
    $scope.addingNote = false;

    $scope.newNote = { note: 'Testing 123', CaseID: 0, NoteID: 0 };

    $scope.getCaseNotes = function (CaseID, UserName, UserRole) {
        $http.get('http://10.34.34.46/BenchViewServices/api/CaseNote/' + CaseID + "/" + UserRole + "/" + UserName).success(function (response) {
            $scope.caseNotes = response;
        })
    };

    $scope.saveCaseNotes = function (CaseID, UserName, NoteID) {

        $scope.addingNote = false;
    };

    $scope.addNote = function () {
        $scope.addingNote = true;
    };

    $scope.cancelNote = function () {
        $scope.newNote.note = '';
        $scope.addingNote = false;
    };

    $scope.editNote = function(caseID, noteID, noteText){
        $scope.newNote.note = noteText;
        $scope.newNote.CaseID = caseID;
        $scope.newNote.NoteID = noteID;
        $scope.addingNote = true;
        $parent.addingNote = true;
    };

    $scope.getCaseNotes($scope.NotesCaseID, $scope.NotesUserName, $scope.NotesUserRole);


}]);
```

As you can see I am having to use `$parent` in places such as `$parent.addingNote`. If I change that to `$scope.addingNote` the function isn't called. The only place I am OK with `$parent` is `$parent.isLoggedIn`. How can I fix this so that it just uses `$scope`?

Comment: Where did you define $scope.loggedin ?

Comment: In another controller called JBenchCtrl

Comment: Is there a link btw these 2 controllers ( JBenchCtrl & CaseNotesCtrl ) ?

Comment: In the index.html there is this `<body ng-controller="JBenchCtrl">` so apparently that is causing this other scope problem?

Comment: I got it a Controller inside an other controller. In my opinion angular js' power comes with separating out clearly the different controllers directives, services, resources etc. Ideally controllers are linked to templates or partials and are used to update the front end and make calls to services or resources. The sooner you start making these separations the sooner you will start making clean and scalable apps that other developers can quickly make sense of.

Comment: Use Angular's controllerAs syntax to fix these problems. **[Todd Motto has a great post on this](http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/)**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use the AngularJS "Controller as" syntax when using ng-controller.

In this case it would be something like this:

```
app.controller('CaseNotesCtrl', function () {
    this.title = 'Some title';
});


<div ng-controller="CaseNotesCtrl as caseNotes">
   {{ caseNotes.title }}
</div>
```

So you it would be easy to you to know which scope are you working with.